# Vuex: How can I update the only element from this object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

With the help of other stack overflow questions I'm this far. 
Basically, it is returning new array updating the single id.
But my `store` `state` is not updating why?
This is my `state` object:

```
allProducts:[
            {
                "product_name": '',
                "code": '',
                "id": ''

            }
        ],
```

And this is my `mutation`.

```
UPDATE_PRODUCT : ({allProducts},payload) =>{
            let updatedProducts = allProducts.map(product => {
                if(product.id === payload.id){
                    return Object.assign({}, product, payload);
                }
                return product;
            })
            allProducts = updatedProducts;
        }
```

If I `console.log(updatedProducts)`, I'm getting perfectly fine `result`. But my `allProducts` is not updating.

Comment: As per the docs here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html
You need to pass `state` as first parameter to your mutation not it's child object. So your mutation should be something like: `UPDATE_PRODUCT : (state,payload)`

Comment: An assignment operation on a destructured object argument (ie `allProducts = updatedProducts`) won't update the value in the object it comes from

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `state` as the first parameter in your mutation method:

```
state:{
    allProducts:[
        {
            "product_name": '',
            "code": '',
            "id": ''

        }
    ]  
}
```

and the mutation :

```
 UPDATE_PRODUCT : (state,payload) =>{
        let updatedProducts = state.allProducts.map(product => {
            if(product.id === payload.id){
                return Object.assign({}, product, payload);
            }
            return product;
        })
        state.allProducts = updatedProducts.slice();
    }
```

Comment: While your solution is correct, the explanation isn't quite right. OP isn't _missing_ anything, they're trying to destructure `allProducts` out of `state` which won't maintain a reference to `state.allProducts` with a direct value assignment

Comment: @Phil thanks for your review, please explain me more

Comment: Okay.... so I cannot destructure like that ... thanks guys @Phil and brahim .. can you also help what this does ? ` Object.assign({}, product, payload);`.. first param is empty, what is it actutally doing... assigning payload to empty obj would be understandable but what abut product?

Comment: The first argument to `Object.assign` is the one modified and returned. Using an empty object ensures you're not accidentally mutating any of the existing objects

Comment: @Phil Thanks but what am I `assigning` it with? `payload` or `product` ?

Comment: @ReyYoung both are being merged into a new, empty object. I suggest you read the documentation ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 1):

you're replacing the reference here, losing the original one

```
allProducts = updatedProducts;
```

instead you should mutate it

```
allProducts.length = 0;
Array.prototype.push.apply(allProducts, updatedProducts);
```